# Refreshing a method within an activity

Tags: java, android

In my android application, I am using google maps and I have a random number generator that will pick randomly from 5 locations and a method that will find the users location. I also added a refresh button that will close the activity and restart it, but I only want it to restart the find users location method. When you refresh the entire activity, the flag randomly changes which I don't want.

```
Button button2=(Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
        button2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick (View w){
                Intent intent = getIntent();
                finish();
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
```

This is the method that will restart the entire activity when the button is pressed but I only want it to refresh the contents of this method

```
 private void handleNewLocation(Location location) {
        Log.d(TAG, location.toString());
    currentLatitude = location.getLatitude();
    currentLongitude = location.getLongitude();

    LatLng latLng = new LatLng(currentLatitude, currentLongitude);

    //mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(currentLatitude, currentLongitude)).title("Current Location"));
    MarkerOptions options = new MarkerOptions()
            .position(latLng)
            .title("You are here");
    mMap.addMarker(options);
    mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom((latLng), 11.0F));
}
```

Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: why not then just call this find_users_location method again your refresh() method

Comment: @tauqir that question is about refreshing an entire activity (I use the same code to refresh mine). I'm looking about how to refresh a certain method

Comment: @Ms and JMeehan1, Sorry my bad. I removed duplicate flag.

Answer (score 0):

If you're set on recreating the Activity, you can pass the `Location` value to the new Activity via the Intent, e.g.

```
Intent intent = getIntent(); // or create a new Intent
finish();
intent.putExtra("LOCATION", myCurrentLocation);
startActivity(intent);
```

Then, in the place where you are choosing a random location, you can check if the intent has a Location, and use that instead, i.e.:

```
Location location;

Intent intent = getIntent();
if(intent.hasExtra("LOCATION")) {
    location = intent.getSerializableExtra("LOCATION");
} else {
    location = getRandomLocation(); // your code for pick a location
}

handleNewLocation(location);
```

To pass the data to the new Activity via the intent, you have several options:

- You can make the `Location` class be serializable (simply by having it `implement Serializable`). This is the simplest approach, and is what the example uses above.
- For slightly faster performance, you can make the class `Parcelable`, and use the `getParcelableExtra` method instead. (Requires more work to make the class `Parcelable`: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcelable.html)
- If your location class is made up of primitives, you can pass those primitives to the intent, and just instantiate a new `Location` instance, e.g., you could do:

  ```
  intent.putExtra("LOCATION_LAT", myCurrentLocation.getLatitude());
  intent.putExtra("LOCATION_LONG", myCurrentLocation.getLongitude());
  ```